# Command line to run a wp-cron.php on Bluehost

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to setup a cron job for my WP All Import plugin. I have tried setting up cron jobs via Bluehost cpanel with the following 4 options:

```sh
php /home2/slotenis/public_html/wp-cron.php?import_key=*****&import_id=9&action=trigger
GET http://www.slotenis.si/wp-cron.php?import_key=*****&import_id=9&action=trigger
/usr/bin/GET http://www.slotenis.si/wp-cron.php?import_key=*****&import_id=9&action=trigger
curl http://www.slotenis.si/wp-cron.php?import_key=*****&import_id=9&action=trigger
```

NONE of them is working.

I have setup an email confirmation every time a cron job is run and I receive the following email:

> cp: cannot stat `exim.pl': No such file or directory
>   cp: not writing through dangling symlink `/var/fake/slotenis/etc/./exim.pl.local'

Can anyone provide me the exact command line to make it working?

Comment: As a side note, there is no `GET` executable in Linux. The `GET` is an HTTP protocol command. We use tools such as curl to generate such a `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `wget`.

```
wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null "https://www.domain.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=*****&import_id=9&action=trigger
```

It's what I use on my sites.

For troubleshooting try visiting the URL yourself. If that doesn't work there's either a problem with the plugin, WordPress or Bluehost.

Comment: No, this one is not working. Same error. The URL itself is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Important to know, the error you are seeing about "cp: cannot stat `exim.pl'" is produced **before** the command actually runs, and it does **not** stop your actual command from working. (This is an issue on Bluehost's side. They recently added broken symlinks in /etc/exim.pl and /etc/exim.pl.local.)

About the actual cron command: If you have special characters like "?" and "&", you need to escape them, e.g. enclose the whole URL in double quotes. It works to run a php script, but if you want to pass query parameters, you don't use the "?" syntax. See [PHP, pass parameters from command line to a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11048835/6834398).

With curl it should work:

```
 curl "http://www.slotenis.si/wp-cron.php?import_key=*****&import_id=9&action=trigger"
```