# PHP 7.0.4 error when using system() with?

Tags: php, command-line

I am trying to run a php inside system().

When I run:

```
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$result = system("php C:{$DS}wamp{$DS}www{$DS}newgemma{$DS}boletos{$DS}boleto_itau.php");
```

Works fine, but when I put ? to send variables to PHP using the code:

```
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$result = system("php C:{$DS}wamp{$DS}www{$DS}newgemma{$DS}boletos{$DS}boleto_itau.php?id=1000");
```

I receive the error "Could not open input file:  C:\wamp\www..

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you have a file named `boleto_itau.php?id=1000` that's not gonna work. Querystrings are an HTTP construct, and (to my knowledge) can't be passed in that fashion via the command line. Out of curiosity, why not simply run an HTTP request (for example via libcurl) since it looks like that's what you're trying to do anyway?

Comment: In addition to what @CollinD said about HTTP versus command line, `?` is not valid in a filename in Windows, so that will probably never work. If you really want to use `system()`, you need to change the way you're calling the program, and change the way the script handles incoming parameters. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048835/php-pass-parameters-from-command-line-to-a-php-script#11049118

Comment: I believe I have found the solution:


boleto_itau.php args id valor 

or


boleto_itau.php args 102 1009.00