# Execute a PHP file with value

Tags: php, exec

I have a bdc.php file which generate a .PDF file with fpdf.

It is working well when the user click on the link but i would like to force the PDF creation when the page is displayed (even if the link is not clicked)

bdc.php retrieve a value named $rid to fill the PDF according to the database.

The code below works : generate PDF, download, and store it on the server :

```
<a href="bdc.php?rid=<?php echo $rid ; ?>" download><span><img src="./images/icon-pdf.png"></span></a>
```

Exec does not work even with forced value or variable :

```
exec ('php bdc.php rid="2055381354"');
exec ('php bdc.php rid=.$rid.');
```

The PDF generate well until the $rid is reached and is blank below

Could you please help me to solve this ?

Regards.

Comment: Command line arguments work differently from query parameters. However, that does not really matter here; as your script only saves a pdf to the server, you could simply set the required variable and include the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048835/php-pass-parameters-from-command-line-to-a-php-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code inside your bdc.php file to convert the CLI arguments to the query string

```
if (!empty($argv[1])) {
  parse_str($argv[1], $_GET);
}
```

Then `bdc.php?rid=123` and `exec('php bdc.php rid=123');` both will work fine.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
exec('php bdc.php rid="'.$rid.'"');
```

Thank you Naveen, works well.

Best Regards.